# jquery datatables buttons extension not working (export to PDF, Excel, etc.)

Tags: excel, pdf, datatables

I'm trying to get the buttons extension to work, but I keep getting errors when attempting to initialize the table.

included files:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jszip.js"></script>
```

I have tried including these as well, but I also get errors that I assume are cascading from the original problem.  I have commented them out at the moment:

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/buttons.print.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/buttons.flash.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/buttons.html5.min.js
```

Using method 1 to create the table:

```
$("#generic-list-table").DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
    ]
} );
```

I get the following error in buttons.min.js:

```
a.init is not a function
```

When using the second method:

```
var table = $('#generic-list-table').DataTable();

new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( table, {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
    ]
} );
```

I get this error:

```
this.c.dom.container is undefined
```

I'm copying the examples exactly. I'm at a loss as to what I'm supposed to be doing differently.

Answer (score 3):

I used the example code (https://www.datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/simple.html) and download all the related references to work local and it works well.

Check [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxiIHP9oSv9RT3Q1NFJoSHhhcWs/view?usp=sharing) to download the example with local files.

This is the code to initiallise

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue but i finally figured it out. You have to load the required files in a correct order.

See if this order sorts your issue

```
<script src="/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="/js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/export_data/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/export_data/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/export_data/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/export_data/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="/js/export_data/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/export_data/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

Mine worked with this order. It appears like some files use variables in others.

In your case, you will need to have

```
<script src="assets/js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
```

Before

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
```

Jquery first, pdfmake follows then the others.

Answer (score 0):

check reference in master page and data table page...may be your reference file available in both..remove from one of them is solve problem for me